# Universal sentence encoding for sentence similarity error

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoding, neural-network, nlp

I'm trying to implement universal sentence encoding on a dataset that consists of two columns of text.The idea is to implement universal sentence coding on both these columns and followed by implementing a neural network. I think I have a problem with the signature variable since the migration from tf1.0 to tf2. Can you help me solve this problem ?

TypeError: Function got an unexpected keyword argument signature

[code]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
# enabling the pretrained model for trainig our custom model using tensorflow hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"
embed = hub.load(module_url)

# creating a method for embedding and will using method for every input layer 
def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)), signature="default", as_dict=True)["default"]

DROPOUT = 0.1

# Taking the question1 as input and ceating a embedding for each question before feed it to neural 
network
q1 = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding_q1 = layers.Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512,))(q1)
# Taking the question2 and doing the same thing mentioned above, using the lambda function
q2 = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding_q2 = layers.Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512,))(q2)

# Concatenating the both input layer
merged = layers.concatenate([embedding_q1, embedding_q2])
merged = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = layers.Dropout(DROPOUT)(merged)

# Normalizing the input layer,applying dense and dropout  layer for fully connected model and to 
avoid overfitting 
merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(merged)
merged = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = layers.Dropout(DROPOUT)(merged)

merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(merged)
merged = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = layers.Dropout(DROPOUT)(merged)

merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(merged)
merged = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = layers.Dropout(DROPOUT)(merged)

# Using the Sigmoid as the activation function and binary crossentropy for binary classifcation as 0 
or 1
merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(merged)
pred = layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[q1,q2], outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[image]